# Javascript Hanging UI on IE6/7

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

Could anyone suggest performance improvements for the function I've written (below, javascript with bits of jquery)? Or point out any glaring, basic flaws? Essentially I have a javascript Google map and a set of list based results too, and the function is fired by a checkbox click, which looks at the selection of checkboxes (each identifying a 'filter') and whittles the array data down accordingly, altering the DOM and updating the Google map markers according to that. There's a 'fake' loader image in there too at the mo that's just on a delay so that it animates before the UI hangs!

```
function updateFilters(currentCheck) {
    if (currentCheck == undefined || (currentCheck != undefined && currentCheck.disabled == false)) {
        var delay = 0;
        if(document.getElementById('loader').style.display == 'none') {
            $('#loader').css('display', 'block');
            delay = 750;
        }
        $('#loader').delay(delay).hide(0, function(){        
            if (markers.length > 0) {
                clearMarkers();
            }

            var filters = document.aspnetForm.filters;
            var markerDataArray = [];
            var filterCount = 0;
            var currentfilters = '';
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

            for (i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
                var currentFilter = filters[i];
                if (currentFilter.checked == true) {
                    var filtername;
                    if (currentFilter.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].textContent != undefined) {
                        filtername = currentFilter.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].textContent;
                    } else {
                        filtername = currentFilter.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerText;
                    }
                    currentfilters += '<li>' + $.trim(filtername) +
                        $.trim(document.getElementById('remhide').innerHTML).replace('#"','#" onclick="toggleCheck(\'' + currentFilter.id + '\');return false;"');
                
                    var nextFilterArray = [];
                    filterCount++;
                    for (k = 0; k < filterinfo.length; k++) {
                        var filtertype = filterinfo[k][0];
                        if (filterinfo[k][0] == currentFilter.id) {
                            var sitearray = filterinfo[k][1];
                            for (m = 0; m < sitearray.length; m++) {
                                var thissite = sitearray[m].split(',');
                                if (filterCount > 1) {
                                    nextFilterArray.push(thissite[2] + '|' + thissite[1]
                                + '|' + thissite[0]);
                                } else {
                                    markerDataArray.push(thissite[2] + '|' + thissite[1]
                                + '|' + thissite[0]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (filterCount > 1) {
                        var itemsToRemove = [];
                        for (j = 0; j < markerDataArray.length; j++) {
                            var exists = false;
                            for (k = 0; k < nextFilterArray.length; k++) {
                                if (markerDataArray[j] == nextFilterArray[k]) {
                                    exists = true;
                                }
                            }
                            if (exists == false) {
                                itemsToRemove.push(j);
                            }
                        }
                        var itemsRemoved = 0;
                        for (j = 0; j < itemsToRemove.length; j++) {
                            markerDataArray.splice(itemsToRemove[j]-itemsRemoved,1);
                            itemsRemoved++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            
            if (currentfilters != '') {
                document.getElementById('appliedfilters').innerHTML = currentfilters;
                document.getElementById('currentfilters').style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                document.getElementById('currentfilters').style.display = 'none';  
            }
            
            if (filterCount < 1) {
               for (j = 0; j < filterinfo.length; j++) {
                    var filtertype = filterinfo[j][0];
                    if (filterinfo[j][0] == 'allvalidsites') {
                        var sitearray = filterinfo[j][1];
                        for (m = 0; m < sitearray.length; m++) {
                            var thissite = sitearray[m].split(',');
                            markerDataArray.push(thissite[2] + '|' + thissite[1]
                                + '|' + thissite[0]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
            
            var resultHTML = '<div id="page1" class="page"><ul>';
            
            var count = 0;
            var page = 1;
            var paging = '<li class="selected"><a href="#" title="' + page + '" onclick="togglePaging(\'' + page + '\');return false;">1</a></li>';
            
            for (i = 0; i < markerDataArray.length; i++) {
                var markerInfArray =  markerDataArray[i].split('|');
                var url = '';
                var name = '';
                var placename = '';
                var region = '';
                var summaryimage = 'images/controls/placeholder.gif';
                var summary = '';
                var flag = 'images/controls/placeholderf.gif';
                
                for (j = 0; j < tsiteinfo.length; j++) {
                    var thissite = tsiteinfo[j].split('|');
                    if (thissite[0] == markerInfArray[2]) {
                        name = thissite[1];
                        placename = thissite[2];
                        region = thissite[3];
                        if (thissite[4] != '') {
                            summaryimage = thissite[4];
                        }
                        summary = thissite[5];
                        if (thissite[6] != '') {
                            flag = thissite[6];
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                for (k = 0; k < sitemapperinfo.length; k++) {
                    var thissite = sitemapperinfo[k].split('|');
                    if (thissite[0] == markerInfArray[2]) {
                        url = thissite[1];
                    }
                }
                
                var markerLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(markerInfArray[1].toString(), markerInfArray[0].toString());

                var infoWindowContent = '<div class="infowindow">' + markerInfArray[2] + ': ';
                
                var siteurl = approot + '/sites/' + url;

                infoWindowContent += '<a href="' + siteurl + '" title="' + name + '"><strong>' + name + '</strong></a>';
                infoWindowContent += '<br /><br/><em>' + placename + ', ' +  region + '</em></div>';

                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: markerLatLng,
                    title: $("<div/>").html(name).text(),
                    shadow: shadow, 
                    icon: image
                });
                addInfo(infoWindow, marker, infoWindowContent);
                    
                markers.push(marker);
                
                count++;
                if ((count > 20) && ((count % 20) == 1)) { // 20 per page
                    page++;
                    resultHTML += '</ul></div><div id="page' + page + '" class="page"><ul>';
                    paging += '<li><a href="#" title="' + page + '" onclick="togglePaging(\'' + page + '\');return false;">' + page + '</a></li>';
                }
                
                resultHTML += '<li><div class="namehead"><h2>' + name + ' <span>' + placename + ', ' + region + '</span></h2></div>' +
                    '<div class="codehead"><h2><img alt="' + region + '" src="' + approot +
                    '/' + flag + '" /> ' + markerInfArray[2] + '</h2></div>' +
                    '<div class="resultcontent"><img alt="' + name + '" src="' + approot +
                    '/' + summaryimage +'" />' + '<p>' + summary + '</p>' + document.getElementById('buttonhide').innerHTML.replace('#',siteurl) + '</div></li>';
            }          
            
            $('#filteredmap .paging').each(function(){
                $(this).html(paging);
            });
                              
            document.getElementById('resultslist').innerHTML = resultHTML + '</ul></div>';
            document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = count + ' ';
            document.getElementById('page1').style.display = 'block';
            
            for (t = 0; t < markers.length; t++) {
                markers[t].setMap(filteredMap); 
            } 
        });
    }
}

function clearMarkers() {
    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(null); 
        markers[i] = null; 
    } 
    markers.length = 0;
}
```

However, I'm suffering from performance issues (UI hanging) specifically in IE6 and 7 when the number of results is high, but not in any other modern browsers, i.e. FF, Chrome, Safari etc. It is *much* worse when the Google map markers are being created and added (if I remove this portion it is still slugglish, but not to the same degree). Can you suggest where I'm going wrong with this?

Thanks in advance :) Please be gentle if you can, I don't do much javascript work and I'm pretty new to it and jquery!

Comment: Would you like to elaborate, Senthil?

Comment: Oh fair enough. I thought perhaps I'd done something awful! As for IE6, not for much longer I hope, but it is dog slow in IE7 too I'm afraid! Initially we weren't going to worry about the older browsers, but the performance is just *so* poor!

Comment: ... when all is said and done what you should get back from the server is (I believe) the data you're adding with `addInfo` which appears to be just html, so at the client, following the ajax query (or following an updatepanel update) you'd extract that html and add it all at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a lot of work to do at the client no matter what.

Why don't you do this at the server instead, constructing all the HTML there, and just refresh the relevant sections with the results of an ajax query?

Comment: First of all, thanks for answering. I agree, I got the sinking feeling that I'd gone about this the wrong way from the start far too late into the project, after investing a lot of time into it. I think it was because originally, the first version of this only updated a Google map, so it was all done through script. However, I'm unsure where to go from here in the way you suggest, as I'm limited time-wise, and don't think I know enough about ajax techniques. Also, I'm not sure how I'd apply this to the Google map update? Thanks again.

Comment: This appears to be an asp.net application - there are plenty of q&as on SO about doing that with jQuery. I don't think that the work you've done with the logic is wasted, you just need to translate it to whatever you're using on the server (C#?) which probably wouldn't be that much work. I'm assuming that the list of checkboxes is generated from the server anyway, so all you need to do is pass to the server the checked state of each object in your list. You could just post the whole form to some page to process. You could also do this with an updatepanel, messier, but easier.

Comment: Thanks for this, I've rolled my sleeves up and moved the filtering logic and list-based html creation to the server (ended up using a web service and jquery), and I've got serious gains :) I can't get away from the Google map marker creation being slow(er) sub IE8, but the speed is now acceptable on the older IE versions. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it worked out!! Sometimes the server is still better at doing things than the client. Though that does seem to be the case less and less these days, number crunching is still often better off left at the server.